# How to fetch records by removing delimiter from SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following values for one attribute in my table.

```
display_Name       Status
Joining :st099     Error
Joining :rp033     Success 
Joining :ts088     Success
```

I want to fetch records for display_Name where status will be Success and it will only give values in rp033, ts088 without way the ":" operator.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(display_name, '[^:]+$')
from t
where status = 'Success';
```

Comment: But can you please help me to understand why this query is not working  :---select COMM_DATE,BUS_PROF,PHONE,STATE,display_name from spt_identity where display_name in (select regexp_substr(NAME, '[^:]+$') as Name
from spt_task_result
where Name like 'Join%' and COMPLETION_STATUS='Error');

Comment: @Sambita . . . New questions should be asked as *questions* not *comments.  Presumably, the names don't match between the two tables, but it is not clear why they don't.

Comment: @Sambita: If it worked, and you are happy with this answer, then please click on the hook to accept the answer. We all then can see that is has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [`INSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) and [`SUBSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(DISPLAY_NAME, INSTR(DISPLAY_NAME, ':') + 1)
       FROM elbat
       WHERE STATUS = 'Success';
```

Answer (score 0):

a straighforward solution assuming `Display Name` will always start with `Joining :`, should just be

```
select replace(Display_name,'Joining :','')  res
   FROM elbat
   WHERE STATUS = 'Success';
```